# Rewrite $ \int_{\{(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^3\text{ s.t. } a=b+c\}}dP_{X,Y,Z}=1 $ as conditions on boxes in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: probability, geometry, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider a 3-dimensional random  vector $(X,Y,Z)$. Let $P_{X,Y,Z}$ be the probability distribution of $(X, Y, Z)$. Assume that
$$
\int_{\mathcal{S}}dP_{X,Y,Z}=1
$$
where $\mathcal{S}\equiv \{(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^3\text{ s.t. } a=b+c\}$.

**My final goal:** I'm interested in rewriting the condition $\int_{\mathcal{S}}dP_{X,Y,Z}=1$ as a collection of zero probability measure conditions on **boxes** in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The idea is that any box in $\mathbb{R}^3$ not intersecting the plane $\mathcal{S}$ should have probability measure equal to zero. Therefore, if we consider enough of these boxes, we should be able to equivalently rewrite $\int_{\mathcal{S}}dP_{X,Y,Z}=1$.

For any two real numbers $(b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, define the boxes $$B(b,c)\equiv \{(x,y,z)\text{ s.t. } x> b+c, y\leq b, z\leq c\}$$ and $$Q(b,c)\equiv \{(x,y,z)\text{ s.t. } x\leq  b+c, y>b, z>c\}$$

I would like your help to see whether the following claim and proof are correct, if not to fix them, if yes to make them more formal.

**Claim:** 
$\int_{\mathcal{S}}dP_{X,Y,Z}=1$ if and only if $P_{X,Y,Z}(B(b,c))=0$ and $P_{X,Y,Z}(Q(b,c))=0$ $\forall(b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

**Proof:**

**Step 1**: it is easy to see that if $\int_{\mathcal{S}}dP_{X,Y,Z}=1$ then $P_{X,Y,Z}(B(b,c))=0$ and $P_{X,Y,Z}(Q(b,c))=0$ $\forall(b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

**Step 2**: we now show that if $P_{X,Y,Z}(B(b,c))=0$ and $P_{X,Y,Z}(Q(b,c))=0$ $\forall(b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ then $\int_{\mathcal{S}}dP_{X,Y,Z}=1$.

Firstly, notice that if $P_{X,Y,Z}(B(b,c))=0$ and $P_{X,Y,Z}(Q(b,c))=0$ $\forall(b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ then
$$
P_{X,Y,Z}(\cup_{b,c} B(b,c))=0
$$
and 
$$
P_{X,Y,Z}(\cup_{b,c} Q(b,c))=0
$$

Secondly notice that $\cup_{b,c} B(b,c)$ is the open [?] region above the plane $\mathcal{S}$ and that $\cup_{b,c} Q(b,c)$ is the open [?] region below the plane $\mathcal{S}$. Hence 
$$
\{\cup_{b,c} B(b,c)\} \cup \{\cup_{b,c} Q(b,c)\}
$$
is the region that is complement to $\mathcal{S}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Therefore, 
$\int_{\mathcal{S}}dP_{X,Y,Z}=1$.

---

**From the comments below: I understand that the step 2 is wrong from the moment in which I take the union over $(b,c)$ because uncountable. Any hint on what to replace? A limit argument for example?**

Comment: What do you mean by "continuously distributed"?  Normally I would assume that this means that $(X, Y, Z)$ has a density on $\mathbb{R}^3$, but this is incompatible with $P$ being concentrated on the two-dimensional set $S$.

Comment: @jochen Thanks for the comment. I've slightly changed the intro to avoid that problem.

Comment: Why is $dP$ defined on $S$ and not $\mathbb R^2?$

Comment: "P is the probability distribution of (Y+Z,Y,Z)" Huh? This is the most misleading notational choice one can imagine. Please stick to $P$ for the probability measure on the probability space $\Omega$ the random variables are defined on, and use anything else for the joint distribution $P_{(X,Y,Z)}$ of $(X,Y,Z)$ (thus, a probability measure on $\mathbb R^3$).

Comment: The proof you are trying to build can be bypassed by quite shorter approaches -- but, if one wishes to stick to it, everything goes smoothly until the last step. Your last step is illegal because you consider uncountable unions (a big no-no in probability theory).

Comment: @Did thanks. I take from your comment that at least the claim is correct (a part from the notational issues). By the last step you mean the entire step 2? Step 2 is what is worrying me indeed, I know less than zero of probability theory. What would you replace?

Comment: No ideas about shorter approaches, but if you are willing to write down something, it would be helpful.

Comment: @Did Is the answer below what you had in mind as shorter approach? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following I will assume, that the random vector is $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ measurable.
Hence we can actually talk about the probability measure of the boxes you defined.

It actually holds a slightly stronger form of your claim:
\begin{equation}
P_{(X,Y,Z)}(S)=1 \Leftrightarrow P_{(X,Y,Z)}(B(b,c))=P_{(X,Y,Z)}(Q(b,c))=0 \, \forall \,(b,c)\in\mathbb{Q}^2
\end{equation}
Proof: "$\Rightarrow$" clear, since $B(b,c)\cap S=\emptyset=Q(b,c)\cap S$.

"$\Leftarrow$" First we show
\begin{equation}
\bigcup_{(b,c)\in\mathbb{Q}^2}B(b,c)=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|x>y+z\}=:A_1 \, .
\end{equation}
"$\subseteq$" clear

"$\supseteq$" Let $(x,y,z)\in A_1$, so $x>y+z$ and we can define $\epsilon:=x-(y+z)>0$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ we can find $p\in [y,y+\epsilon/2)\cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $q\in[z,z+\epsilon/2)\cap\mathbb{Q}$. With this we have $x=y+z+\epsilon>p+q$, so $(x,y,z)\in Q(p,q)$.

Similarly it holds that
\begin{equation}
\bigcup_{(b,c)\in\mathbb{Q}^2}Q(b,c)=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|x<y+z\}=:A_2\, .
\end{equation}

Together we get that $S^c=A_1\cup A_2$. Since $A_1$ and $A_2$ are disjoint and both a countable union of nullsets we get 
\begin{equation}
P_{(X,Y,Z)}(S^c)=0\, .
\end{equation}
qed

**P.S.** I don't have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you add to your answer what is $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Also, as a minor comment, is the proof you suggest generalisable to this case:  fix $r\in \mathbb{N}$ and $d\equiv r+\binom{r}{2}$ and let 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{S}\equiv \{(b_1,b_2,..., b_d)\in \mathbb{R}^{d}: \text{ } & b_{r+1}=b_1-b_2, b_{r+2}=b_1-b_3, ...,b_{2r-1}=b_1-b_r, \\
&b_{2r}=b_2-b_3, ..., b_{3r-3}=b_2-b_r,\\
&...,\\
& b_d=b_{r-1}-b_r\}
\end{aligned}
$$
(when $r=2$ ($d=3$) we have $\mathcal{S}$ as in my question). Take a random vector of $d$ components with probability distribution $P$ and assume $\int_{\mathcal{S}}dP=1$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ are the rational numbers. As to your second comment, I guess it should work. Would be a bit lengthy though.

Comment: I still have 2 doubts to answer before accepting: (1) is it correct to say that $A_1$ and $A_2$ are countable unions because $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable? (2) why you said that your claim is stronger than mine? What is the relation between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{Q}^2$?

Comment: (2): $\mathbb{Q}^2\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$. please take a look at the definition of the rational numbers and the real numbers, you can't really understand the real numbers if you don't know the rational numbers.
(1) yes that's correct. $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and therefore $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is, too.
The most important fact you need to know about the relation between rational and real numbers is, that the real numbers are the closure (regarding the metric $|\cdot|$) of the rational numbers.  the rational numbers are dense in the real numbers, which I used in my answer in the step "$\supseteq$".

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Still, I don't get why your claim is stronger than mine. Naively (and apologies if I'm missing something obvious), since $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and you show that the claim holds $\forall (b,c)\in \mathbb{Q}^2$, it seems to me that your claim is weaker than mine (which was instead $\forall (b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^2$). Where am I wrong?

Comment: well first of all, it's correct that the statement with $\forall (b,c)\in\mathbb{Q}^2$ is weaker than $\forall (b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

what i meant though was that since the "$\Rightarrow$" direction is trivial, the actually interesting part of the claim is "$\Leftarrow$". and for this direction my claim is stronger, since it weakens the preconditions.

Comment: I see. Hence, to sum up, is it correct to claim : $\int_{\mathcal{S}} dP=1$ $\Rightarrow$ $P(Q(b,c))=P(B(b,c))=0$ $\forall (b,c)\in \mathbb{R}^2$; $P(Q(b,c))=P(B(b,c))=0$ $\forall (b,c)\in \mathbb{Q}^2$ $\Rightarrow$  $\int_{\mathcal{S}} dP=1$ ?

Comment: yes that's correct!

Comment: Thanks, please help with this if you can https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3081147/rewrite-int-mathcalsdp-x-1-as-conditions-on-boxes-in-mathbbrd